# Is it better to use channel 13 than channel 11 on 2.4GHz band

Tags: router, wireless, ieee-802.11, lan, bandwidth

When I analyzed the wifi networks in my area, most of them are set on channel 1 and channel 6, so it would be most wise for me to set it on channel 11.

My router however, provides the option to set it on channel 13. Wouldn't it be even better for me to put it on channel 13, as that is even further away from the lower channels, or would you recommend me to put it on channel 11?

Thanks!

Comment: Setting for channel 13 will still overlap with anything set for channel 11.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Channels 1, 6, and 11 are spaced far enough apart that they don’t overlap. On a non-MIMO setup (i.e. 802.11 a, b, or g) you should always try to use channel 1, 6, or 11. If you use 802.11n with 20MHz channels, stick to channels 1, 6, and 11 — if you want to use 40MHz channels, be aware that the airwaves might be congested, unless you live in a detached house in the middle of nowhere.

In your case selecting 13 would be perfect, since most are at 1 and 6 as you wrote. Setting channels as far as possible away from other active networks.

Good read on SuperUser: https://superuser.com/questions/443178/is-it-better-to-use-a-crowded-2-4ghz-wi-fi-channel-1-6-11-or-unused-3-4-8

Comment: Right, but note that some devices can't use channel 13.

Answer (score 3):

Some further info:
https://www.howtogeek.com/402142/why-wi-fi-channels-12-13-and-14-are-illegal-in-the-usa/

To summarise, if you're in the USA, channels 12 and 13 are only in low-power mode, since they compete for space with a company which has rights to that part of the spectrum there.

However in other parts of the world, you're fine to use those channels. But it's why you won't see channel 13 in a lot of the literature talking about channels "1, 6 and 11 only".

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar situation (channels 1, 6 and 11 pretty crowded, channel 13 much less), and my speed tests show that setting the router to channel 13 does give me some extra bandwidth.

RF interference is not a binary "Yes/No" state, it is at maximum when the base frequencies match and gets smaller as the base frequencies get further apart. So, assuming channels 1 and 6 are not an option, having two networks in proximity on channels 11 and 13 is better than having them both on channel 11.